# TLS versions for Java in Oracle Database

Tags: java, oracle, tls1.2

I am using a pl/sql procedure which calls a java class in Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0.
The java class should make a call to a webservice, which however supports only TLS 1.1 and 1.2.
I've checked the Java version as follows:

```
create or replace function test_get_java_property (prop in varchar2) return varchar2 is language java name 'java.lang.System.getProperty (java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
SELECT dbms_java.get_ojvm_property (PROPSTRING => 'java.version') FROM dual;
```

The result of the query is "1.6.0_43" and if I type "java –version" from the path "E:\oracle\product\11.2\dbhome_1\jdk\bin" I get this:

```
Java version "1.5.0_51"
Java (TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_51-b10)
Java HotSpot (TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 1.5.0_51-b10, mixed mode)
```

So the Java version doesn't support TLS 1.1 or 1.2. For this reason TLS 1.1 or 1.2 must be enabled.
Maybe it's necessary to update the version of java in the database, if it is possible.
If so, how should I proceed?
I cannot update the Oracle version.
I appreciate any other kind of solution.

Comment: Oracle didn't offer a way to upgrade the embedded JVM until 12.1, so you're out of luck there. I'd recommend a proxy. https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2370567_1.html

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a proxy, i.e. a Java program which talks to the database with no security and talks TLS to the web service.

Comment: The web service requires TLS.
The query:

select UTL_HTTP.REQUEST('https://pre-sdp.cloud.lmbg.audi.vwg/loomService',null,'file:E:\BOOM_LOOM\Wallets\VODAFONE',null) FROM DUAL;

Returns:
ORA-06512: a "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1720
ORA-29024: La convalida del certificato non è riuscita.
29273. 00000 -  "HTTP request failed"
*Cause:    The UTL_HTTP package failed to execute the HTTP request.
*Action:   Use get_detailed_sqlerrm to check the detailed error message.
           Fix the error and retry the HTTP request.

The wallet is correctly configured

Comment: This is why you need a proxy. This is a program that talks to the database according to the requirements of the database and to the web service according to its requirements.You connect to the web service as a client using TLS. You connect to the database as a client using a plain socket. When you receive a message you pass it on to the database. You receive the response from the database and send it to the web service.

Comment: The web service supports TLS 1.1 and 1.2 and has a certificate. I have created a certificate portfolio and the Oracle client has TLS 1.2. The web service is in the cloud but is in the same network as the client. I am able to reach the service through SOAPUI but not with the SQL command that I have indicated. What are the limitations for failing to reach the service through PL / SQL?